# My App Stops working when i add the code given below

Tags: android, xml, layout

This is the code that causes this problem:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    double height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    double width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    int Orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(Orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(5,5));
    }
```

When i put it inside my complete code like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
    char decimalSeparator = currencyFormatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();
    mDecimalSeparator = Character.toString(decimalSeparator);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    double height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    double width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    int Orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(Orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(5,5));
    }


    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Why does this happen the message i get is app stopped working.

Here is my logcat:

```
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow$LayoutParams
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.TableRow.mapIndexAndColumns(TableRow.java:164)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.TableRow.getVirtualChildCount(TableRow.java:149)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.TableRow.getColumnsWidths(TableRow.java:289)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.TableLayout.findLargestCells(TableLayout.java:508)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:473)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1220)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:321)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2200)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-14 19:14:42.067: E/AndroidRuntime(12380):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ResultText"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="#AAAAAA"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/InputText"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />


</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/memoryStatText"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMAdd"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="M+"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMRemove"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="M-"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMC"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="MC"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMR"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="MR"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClearAll"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="C"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDel"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="del"
    android:gravity="fill" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="1"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="2"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="3"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="4"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="+"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="-"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />


</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="5"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="6"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="7"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="8"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="/"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="x"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="fill" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="9"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button0"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="0"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPeriod"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="."
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSign"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="±"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPercent"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"
    android:gravity="fill"    
    android:text="%"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonEqual"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"
    android:gravity="fill"    
    android:text="="
    android:onClick="ProcessInput" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSin"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166" 
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:text="sin"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCos"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"
    android:gravity="fill"    
    android:text="cos"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTan"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166" 
    android:gravity="fill"   
    android:text="tan"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSinInverse"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="0.166"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:gravity="fill"   
        android:text="@string/sin_inv"
        android:onClick="ProcessInput"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCosInverse"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"
    android:gravity="fill" 
    android:textSize="8sp"  
    android:text="@string/cos_inv"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTanInverse"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"
    android:gravity="fill" 
    android:textSize="8sp"  
    android:text="@string/tan_inv"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"/>


</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPower"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"
    android:textSize="12sp"      
    android:text="pow"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLog10"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="log"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLoge"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="ln"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSquare"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="sqr"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSquareRoot"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="sqrt"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonFactorial"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="x!"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You need to post the logcat dump of the crash, otherwise we cannot tell why the crash occurs.

Comment: you put the setContentview last which is not suppose to be so

Comment: show your logcat here

Comment: I have updated my question to include logcat

Comment: Show your main.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Update like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
    char decimalSeparator = currencyFormatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();
    mDecimalSeparator = Character.toString(decimalSeparator);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    double height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    double width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    int Orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(Orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(5,5));
    }
```

You had placed  `setContentView(R.layout.main);` at the end.

Updated Answer

This is the problem

```
btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(5,5));
```

Your button must be inside a Table Layout and you are using wrong Layout Params. Check the layout params you are using.

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
```

to be

```
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
```

Comment: import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

This is what i have imported.

Comment: Then try to import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams instead